# How to fix Android file system error

Tags: file-system

There's a corrupt file on my (rooted) Android device
at `/data/anr/traces.txt`

when I `cd` to this directory with `adb shell`, or try to do `cat` or `rm` on this file I get `I/O error`

Most importantly it prevents me from having a TWRP backup, as it fails at reading this file,

How can I either delete it or fix it?

Deleting `anr` folder with ES File Explorer or Cyanogen Built In File Manager results in error, also these file explorers don't actually show any files inside `anr` folder

update on comment:

running fsck.f2fs outputs
```

```
~ # fsck.f2fs -f /dev/block/mmcblk0p48
Info: Force to fix corruption
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 50454272 (24635 MB)
Info: MKFS version
  "Linux version 3.10.84-perf-g329ac5f (hudsoncm@ilclbld30) (gcc version 4.9.x-google 20140827 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 20 17:03:52 CDT 2016"
Info: FSCK version
  from "Linux version 3.10.84-perf-g0ec7138 (hudsoncm@ilclbld87) (gcc version 4.9.x-google 20140827 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 3 05:01:11 CST 2015"
    to "Linux version 3.10.84-perf-g0ec7138 (hudsoncm@ilclbld87) (gcc version 4.9.x-google 20140827 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 3 05:01:11 CST 2015"
Info: superblock features = 1 :  encrypt
Info: superblock encrypt level = 0, salt = 00000000000000000000000000000000
Info: total FS sectors = 50454272 (24635 MB)
Info: CKPT version = 10de4e
Info: checkpoint state = 5 :  compacted_summary unmount

[FSCK] Unreachable nat entries                        [Ok..] [0x0]
[FSCK] SIT valid block bitmap checking                [Ok..]
[FSCK] Hard link checking for regular file            [Ok..] [0x0]
[FSCK] valid_block_count matching with CP             [Ok..] [0x2beeaa]
[FSCK] valid_node_count matcing with CP (de lookup)   [Ok..] [0x723f]
[FSCK] valid_node_count matcing with CP (nat lookup)  [Ok..] [0x723f]
[FSCK] valid_inode_count matched with CP              [Ok..] [0x69ed]
[FSCK] free segment_count matched with CP             [Ok..] [0x12ca]
[FSCK] next block offset is free                      [Ok..]
[FSCK] fixing SIT types
[FSCK] other corrupted bugs                           [Ok..]
```

but next `ls -l /data/anr/` reveals that file is still corrupted

i know exact `inode` of the offender

```
|-- anr <ino = 0x476b>, <encrypted (0)>
|   |-- traces.txt <ino = 0x3c19>, <encrypted (0)>
```

Any ideas? I dont want to format /data i have stuff on it I want to backup with TWRP

Comment: Did you try `fsck` ?

Comment: @GokulNC please see update

Comment: You wrote `cat` gives you an error as well – but didn't specify which way you've used cat. I assume you've already tried something like `echo foo > traces.txt`? Not that I give it much hope, but worth a try I'd say. Apart from that, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/143138/143340) on our sister-site might be helpful – if `debugfs` is available on your device.

Comment: @Izzy no, `echo` gives same error, `debugfs` is not available on my system :(

Comment: OK, sorry for that – but was worth a try. I'm out of ideas then. The only thing I rawly can think of is finding out what block the iNode belongs to, and mark that as "bad". But I've got no idea how to do that.